# How to save a foreignkey field while saving a HTML form in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, view, foreign-keys

I want to save a html form data into django model but it has a foreign key field from another model. How can I save a form which has FK field??

My models:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    title =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description =models.TextField(blank=True) 
    price =models.IntegerField()
    photo_main= models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y%m%d/") 
    photo_1= models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y%m%d/", blank= True)
    photo_2= models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y%m%d/", blank= True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
    dishorder= models.ForeignKey(Dish,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    quantity =models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

My views:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        order= Order(
            name=name,
            email=email,
            phone=phone,
            quantity=quantity)
        order.save()
        messages.success(request, "Your order has been submitted.")
    return render(request,"dishes/order.html")
```

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("dish",views.dish,name="dish"),
    path("dish/<pk>",views.dishsingle,name="dishsingle"),
    path("order",views.order,name="order"),
]
```

My template dishes/order.html

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
          <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" value="MAKE AN ORDER">
      </form>
```

While submitting this html form, I would like the foreignkey field dishorder to be saved on the backend as well. When I check the admin page, order is saved but without the name of the dish. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you should use Django Forms for it. Anyway, it is not clear to me, to which dish you wanna link?  Where and when does this info come from?

Comment: It worked. I passed the pk of the dish to order and saved as dish=Dish.objects.get(pk=pk) in the view and made the necessary changes to the templates.